# Calling Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop() gives black screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview

I have a open Chrome custom tab and then I open another app. This other app then opens my app via Asset Links and somehow my navigation stack is not preserved correctly. This means that a new page/widget is placed on top of my custom tab and I need the user to land on the custom tab again (I have another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75181241/when-opening-app-via-asset-links-the-navigation-stack-becomes-wrong) on this also, but now I just want to try a dirty fix).

So I want to just close that added page/widget. If I manually navigate back on my Android device via the back arrow, it works great and the added page/widget is closed and I see my custom tab.

I have tried calling

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

If I call "pop" once I get a black page and still if I then manually navigate back I come back to the custom tab. If I pop 2 times like this

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)..pop()..pop();
```

I get

```
The following assertion was thrown building Navigator-[LabeledGlobalKey#ad310](dirty, dependencies: [HeroControllerScope, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: NavigatorState#e4365(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5203 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.
```

Still I can manually navigate back to the custom tab... Any ideas on mow I can close this widget on top and get back to my custom tab?

Comment: root is null so you are getting this error . 1st check root is still in the background . then you can go back to the root

Comment: How do I check the root is still in the background, and then how do I go back to the root?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `rootNavigator: true` which is causing you to pop from the first instance in your navigator. The navigator is like a list of pages that you opened in the order you opened them. That attribute is forcing all routing from the first page on the navigator, so when you pop, you remove everything and remain with no screen at all.
Try `Navigator.of(context).pop();`

Comment: I have tried this, that was my first attempt. Same result :(